# UIImage animation behind ImageVisualEffectView cannot reflect effect on ImageVisualEffectView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

```
UIImage *bk = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [filepathWanted path]];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.BackgroundView
                                  duration:1.0f
                                   options:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut
                                animations:^{
                                    self.BackgroundView.image = bk;
                                } completion:nil];
```

As the code shown above, I want an ImageView's image (BackgroundView.image) changed to another one (bk) with animation, but the backgroud view is behind a ImageVisualEffectView that is a blurred view. And what I expected to see is that the ImageView can fade in or fade out and I can see it through the blurred view, but actually it is not, it just changed immediately to the second image after the duration of animation. 
[image]
Any helps?

Comment: you want imageview fadein/fadeout ?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the imageview's image with animation fadein fadeout, and during the animation, the blurred UIVisualEffectView should blur the ImageView.